# Azure DevOps with Boomi (or) Jenkins with Boomi for CI/CD automation with various stages

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops-server

Are there any methods by which we can integrate Dell Boomi with Azure DevOps or Jenkins to implement CI/CD automation with various stages including unit testing and SonarQube etc?
Any help with tools details and approaches is highly appreciated.

Previously I have tried this integration process using the Bash scripts (Link for Scripts: **Dell Boomi** ) but it wasn't helpful as we are facing many blockers while executing the script and after fixing it also we were unable to connect to Boomi platform.
I want to apply DevOps concepts to the Boomi platform, Where I need help to integrate the Azure DevOps platform with Boomi (or) Jenkins platform with Boomi.